# Simple parallelism using @sync @async in Julia

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, julia

I have a problem where I would like to execute a number of statements in parallel that are independent of each other.

I have read plenty of examples that suggest this toy example should work:

```
function f1(x,y,z)
  @sync @async begin
    # these two statements can be computed independently
    v1 = x+y; 
    v2 = y+z;
  end
  return v1*v2
end
```

However, it seems that the @sync part is not waiting for the results to be completed because I get the following error:

```
y1 = f1(1,2,3);
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: v1 not defined
```

I have succeeded in making it work like this:

```
function f2(x,y,z)
  v1 = @async x+y;
  v2 = @async y+z;
  return wait(v1)*wait(v2)
end
```

However, in many examples that I have seen, the wait statement seems to be unnecessary if one uses a @sync block.

I'm using Julia 0.6.2.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `@async` creates a closure around the expression you pass to it. You can see it by running:

```
julia> @macroexpand @async begin
       v1 = x+y;
       v2 = y+z;
       end
:((Base.async_run_thunk)((()->begin  # task.jl, line 335:
                begin  # REPL[22], line 2:
                    v1 = x + y # REPL[22], line 3:
                    v2 = y + z
                end
            end)))
```

This has the implication that `v1` and `v2` variables will not be visible outside the closure unless they are present in the enclosing function scope.

To fix this you can add `local v1, v2` statement at the beginning of `f1`:

```
julia> function f1(x,y,z)
           local v1, v2
           @sync @async begin
               v1 = x+y;
               v2 = y+z;
           end
           return v1*v2
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1(1,2,3)
15
```

and as you can see all worked as expected.

Additionally if your enclosing scope were not a function but a global scope you would have to use `global` keyword to get what you want:

```
julia> x,y,z = 1,2,3
(1, 2, 3)

julia> @sync @async begin
          global v1 = x+y;
          global v2 = y+z;
       end
Task (done) @0x0000000018be30f0

julia> v1*v2
15
```